# python using regex with groups, how do you get all the matches?

Tags: python

I'm using python re to match groups. When I use that with a + I'm seem to "lose" the first matches. Only the last one is seen by result.group(1). I do see them in result.group(0), but that doesn't really help. Is there a way to see all the matches that group(1) matched?

In the example below I'd like group(1) to print %one %two %three, not %three

(group(0) won't work because in the real world that's stuff after the initial match)

```
import sys
import re

line = '%one %two %three'
re_rule = re.compile("\s*(%\w+\s*)+")

result = re_rule.match(line)
if result:
    print("DBG:", result.group(1))
    print("DBG:", result.group(0))
```

Comment: You wouldn't accept a list as `findall` gives? This seems to work: `re.compile("(%\w+)").findall(line)` (gives `['%one', '%two', '%three']`)

Comment: Did you try to use `re_rule.findall()` instead of `match()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

line = '%one %two %three'
re_rule = re.compile("%(\w+)")
f
result = re_rule.findall(line)

print(result)
```

Output is:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

The trick here is using `findall`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.findall

The `re` engine only keeps the last iteration of repeated capturing groups, but we can circumvent this behaviour by encapsulating a repeating non-capturing group in a capturing group like

```
re_rule = re.compile("((?:%\w+\s*)+)")
```

Comment: same issue with group(0), there's stuff after the one, two, three that I don't want. I guess I should have added that to the example but I was trying to keep it simple

Comment: So do you want one match containing the first three tokens that start with `%`? `"((?:%\w+\s?){3})"`

Comment: imagine the data line is something  like "word+ : other+"  I'd like an expression that matches word+.  imagine word+ is messy enough that a group is needed. Can I get at all the data that group(1) matches? my example up above group(1) only shows the last match of the group.

Comment: @kdubs repeating capturing groups only match the last iteration.  Why don't you post a couple of lines of the real data and we'll come up with something

Comment: @kdubs to get around that, you use a non-capturing group that repeats wrapped in a capturing group, like `"((?:%\w+\s*)+)"`

Comment: yeah. I think I just stumbled on to that. so it appears you can't get at the group matches, but you can rearrange what the group is. If you change your answer around, I can mark it as accepted.